# Differential form of Massieu’s function

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, differential-equations

Massieu’s function is given by:

$$F_{M}=-\frac{U}{T}+S$$

And its differential form is given by:

$$dF_{M}=\frac{U}{T^{2}}dT+\frac{P}{T}dV$$

Well, it seems that:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}=0$$

How can that be?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathrm{d}(-U/T)= -\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{T} + \frac{U}{T^2}\,\mathrm{d}T$ and hence $$ \mathrm{d}F_{\mathrm{M}} =-\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{T} + \frac{U}{T^2}\,\mathrm{d}T + \mathrm{d}S  \quad .$$

Using $ \mathrm{d}U=T\, \mathrm{d}S -  p\,\mathrm{d}V$ in the above equation gives the desired result.